# Grab information from the registry using PowerShell 4.0

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0, powershell-4.0

I have a script that runs just fine on Server 2008R2 using PowerShell 3.0. 
However, when running the same script on Server 2012R2 and PowerShell 4.0, the variables comes back blank.

I am trying to read 2 values from the registry.

[image: Registry Key]

Here is the script:

```
#GET CRM INSTALL NAME FROM REGISTRY
$GetInstallname = ( Get-ItemProperty -Path HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\eWare\Mappings\|foreach {$_.PSBase.properties}|
 Select NAME | 
 where {$_.Name -notlike ("PSPath")} |
 WHERE {$_.Name -notlike ("PSParentPath")}|
 where {$_.Name -notlike ("PSChildName")} |
 where {$_.Name -notlike ("PSDrive")} |
 where {$_.Name -notlike ("PSProvider")} )
 $CRMName = $GetInstallname -replace "/","" -replace "@{Name=","" -replace "}","" 

#GET CRM INSTALL DIR FROM REGISTRY
$GetInstallDIR = ( Get-ItemProperty -Path HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\eWare\Mappings\|foreach {$_.PSBase.properties}|
 Select VALUE | 
 where {$_.Value -notlike ("Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\Registry::HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\eWare\Mappings\")} |
 WHERE {$_.Value -notlike ("Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\Registry::HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\eWare")}|
 where {$_.Value -notlike ("Mappings")} |
 where {$_.Value -notlike ("HKLM")} |
 where {$_.Value -notlike ("Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\Registry")} )
 $CRMPath = $GetInstallDIR -replace "@{Value=","" -replace "}","" -replace "WWWRoot",""


 $CRMNAME
 $CRMPath
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While it does not fix your existing script, I would recommend just using `Get-Item`, and the registry provider as such:

```
$CRM = Get-Item -Path HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\eWare\Mappings\
$GetInstallName = $CRM.Property
$GetInstallDIR = $CRM.GetValue($GetInstallName)
```

Comment: Thank you TheMadTechnician! That fixed my problem!